# Google App Engine - javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm an old user of GAE, but recently, after some updates of my OS X to Mavericks DP4 and Java SDK(1.6, 1.7, 1.8) and Goolge App Engine SDK(1.8.1, 1.8.2), I cannot start my GAE application again, and the stack trace seems completely confusing, do you know why? It works completely fine on my local machine, but once deployed to the hosting platform, it cannot be started, every request results into the following stack trace, the project is configured as
1. use JDK1.7 (Also, I have tried 1.6)
2. use SDK1.8.2 (also tried 1.8.1, no luck)

```
 2013-07-23 16:32:01.525 /_ah/spi/BackendService.logMessages 500 504ms 19kb
10.43.73.135 - - [23/Jul/2013:16:32:01 -0700] "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.logMessages HTTP/1.1" 500 19888 - - "3-dot-goo-apple.appspot.com" ms=504 cpu_ms=240 cpm_usd=0.002223 pending_ms=183 app_engine_release=1.8.2 instance=00c61b117c6d26217f5ce7350f5ea3e519ed8765
W 2013-07-23 16:32:01.508
EXCEPTION 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-42b947a416991b23(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:359)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:740)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:717)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
E 2013-07-23 16:32:01.508
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:740)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:717)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
W 2013-07-23 16:32:01.511
EXCEPTION 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-42b947a416991b23(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:359)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:740)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:717)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
E 2013-07-23 16:32:01.511
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:740)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:717)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
W 2013-07-23 16:32:01.514
EXCEPTION 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-42b947a416991b23(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:359)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:740)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:717)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
E 2013-07-23 16:32:01.514
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:740)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:717)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
W 2013-07-23 16:32:01.516
Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@14c4af3{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~goo-apple/3.368997267257921798}
org.mortbay.util.MultiException[java.lang.NullPointerException, java.lang.NullPointerException, java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:656)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:740)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:717)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:740)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:717)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:740)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:717)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:740)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:717)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
C 2013-07-23 16:32:01.521
Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:228)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:740)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:717)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Null Pointer Exception,  Illegal Argument Exception (possibly from the null pointer argument).

Comment: But in the end it's caused by this exception "Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed.", what do you think?

Comment: As a work around, I ended up using a virtual win7 to upload the same piece of code. And everything works great. I'm not sure if it's some MAC-Java conflicts but I highly suspect that.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?  Having the same on my mac.

Comment: no, buddy. use a virtual machine... it's definitely a java env problem. just don't know if it's from gae or from my local env.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is due to .jsp files are getting compiled with higher compiler(8) than expected(7). Change all compilation levels to lower one(i.e. 7) also **change the jdk path given in eclipse configuration settings file in the same folder where .exe is located.**